# Unwanted random value found in profile for custom user

Tags: python, django

I'm following https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/auth/customizing/#a-full-example , to create user with email as username.

I'm also create a one-to-one relationship, with a `profile` table. The `profile` table contains a API key column

I looks at the `user` table and `profile` table. Both of them looks fine. If I have 3 records in `user` table, I will only have 3 records in `profile` table, as they are one-to-one relationship.

---

However, when I look login into admin page. Things doesn't sound right. Each user is associated with 2 API keys. The first API key seem to be a random generated value, another API key is a valid API key from DB.

[image]

Here's the current database.

```
snapweb=# select * from accounts_myuser;
 id | password                   |          last_login           |          email           | is_active | is_admin
----+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-------------------------------+
  2 | pbkdf2_sha256$120000$w7OlH |                               | yccheok@yahoo.com        | t         | f
  1 | pbkdf2_sha256$120000$tWA6Y | 2018-08-21 05:07:28.391689+00 | root@root.com            | t         | t
  3 | pbkdf2_sha256$120000$TkKAE |                               | yancheng.cheok@gmail.com | t         | f
(3 rows)

snapweb=# select * from accounts_profile;
 id |               api_key                | user_id
----+--------------------------------------+---------
  1 | d6ee9b31-6847-4b7d-8151-98b133f21c42 |       1
  2 | c6f3718e-41ee-4759-984a-63c405b32fc4 |       2
  3 | 10c64d48-416f-4fd7-b01d-4328d2536ea2 |       3
(3 rows)
```

Now, the value shown in admin page is

```
API KEY: 6cb1b77f-6ab0-464d-9176-d0ed20402b8c: API KEY: 10c64d48-416f-4fd7-b01d-4328d2536ea2
```

When you refresh the page, it will change to

```
API KEY: b4a07773-a3e0-4fcc-bf5c-245935cd0687: API KEY: 10c64d48-416f-4fd7-b01d-4328d2536ea2
```

---

**Do you have any idea why this strange behavior occurs?**

Here's are the code

### models.py

```
import uuid
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.dispatch import receiver
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import (
    BaseUserManager, AbstractBaseUser
)

class MyUserManager(BaseUserManager):
    def create_user(self, email, password=None):
        """
        Creates and saves a User with the given email and 
        password.
        """
        if not email:
            raise ValueError('Users must have an email address')

        user = self.model(
            email=self.normalize_email(email),
        )

        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user

    def create_superuser(self, email, password):
        """
        Creates and saves a superuser with the given email and 
        password.
        """
        user = self.create_user(
            email,
            password=password,
        )
        user.is_admin = True
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user


class MyUser(AbstractBaseUser):
    email = models.EmailField(
        verbose_name='email address',
        max_length=255,
        unique=True,
    )
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    objects = MyUserManager()

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.email

    def has_perm(self, perm, obj=None):
        "Does the user have a specific permission?"
        # Simplest possible answer: Yes, always
        return True

    def has_module_perms(self, app_label):
        "Does the user have permissions to view the app `app_label`?"
        # Simplest possible answer: Yes, always
        return True

    @property
    def is_staff(self):
        "Is the user a member of staff?"
        # Simplest possible answer: All admins are staff
        return self.is_admin


class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(MyUser, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    api_key = models.UUIDField(default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False, unique=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return 'API KEY: ' + str(self.api_key)


@receiver(post_save, sender=MyUser)
def create_or_update_user_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        Profile.objects.create(user=instance)
        instance.profile.save()
```

### admin.py

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.auth.models import Group
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin as BaseUserAdmin
from django.contrib.auth.forms import ReadOnlyPasswordHashField

from accounts.models import MyUser
from accounts.models import Profile

class UserCreationForm(forms.ModelForm):
    """A form for creating new users. Includes all the required
    fields, plus a repeated password."""
    password1 = forms.CharField(label='Password', widget=forms.PasswordInput)
    password2 = forms.CharField(label='Password confirmation', widget=forms.PasswordInput)

    class Meta:
        model = MyUser
        fields = ('email',)

    def clean_password2(self):
        # Check that the two password entries match
        password1 = self.cleaned_data.get("password1")
        password2 = self.cleaned_data.get("password2")
        if password1 and password2 and password1 != password2:
            raise forms.ValidationError("Passwords don't match")
        return password2

    def save(self, commit=True):
        # Save the provided password in hashed format
        user = super().save(commit=False)
        user.set_password(self.cleaned_data["password1"])
        if commit:
            user.save()
        return user


class UserChangeForm(forms.ModelForm):
    """A form for updating users. Includes all the fields on
    the user, but replaces the password field with admin's
    password hash display field.
    """
    password = ReadOnlyPasswordHashField()

    class Meta:
        model = MyUser
        fields = ('email', 'password', 'is_active', 'is_admin')

    def clean_password(self):
        # Regardless of what the user provides, return the initial value.
        # This is done here, rather than on the field, because the
        # field does not have access to the initial value
        return self.initial["password"]


class MyCustomUserInline(admin.StackedInline):
    model = Profile
    can_delete = True
    verbose_name = Profile


class UserAdmin(BaseUserAdmin):
    # The forms to add and change user instances
    form = UserChangeForm
    add_form = UserCreationForm

    # The fields to be used in displaying the User model.
    # These override the definitions on the base UserAdmin
    # that reference specific fields on auth.User.
    list_display = ('email', 'is_admin')
    list_filter = ('is_admin',)
    fieldsets = (
        (None, {'fields': ('email', 'password')}),
        ('Permissions', {'fields': ('is_admin',)}),
    )
    # add_fieldsets is not a standard ModelAdmin attribute. UserAdmin
    # overrides get_fieldsets to use this attribute when creating a user.
    add_fieldsets = (
        (None, {
            'classes': ('wide',),
            'fields': ('email', 'password1', 'password2')}
        ),
    )
    search_fields = ('email',)
    ordering = ('email',)
    filter_horizontal = ()

    inlines = (MyCustomUserInline, )

# Now register the new UserAdmin...
admin.site.register(MyUser, UserAdmin)
# ... and, since we're not using Django's built-in permissions,
# unregister the Group model from admin.
admin.site.unregister(Group)
```

---

### Update

After changing the code from

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(MyUser, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    api_key = models.UUIDField(default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False, unique=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return 'API KEY: ' + str(self.api_key)
```

to

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(MyUser, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    api_key = models.UUIDField(default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False, unique=True)

    def __str__(self):
        if hasattr(self, 'user'):
            return 'API KEY -> ' + str(self.api_key)
        else:
            return ''
```

I'm some how able to partially "eliminate" the problem to (Not sure why there's still a double colon `:`)

[image]

**Now, the question back to, why there's a `Profile` object without `MyUser` being created at the first place? How can I completely eliminate the problem? (Not even showing the double colon `:`)**

Comment: can you move `__str__` to User model and print it with `self.profile.api_key if self.profile else None`. I'm curios what the result will be look like. And print any text in this `__str__` in profile. I've a feeling that this got called two times from two different users.

Comment: a better idea is change the `__str__` in profile to `print (self.user)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to change the attribute `verbose_name = Profile` in your `InlineModelAdmin` and use a *string* instead. **Edit:** Also, you should let the function `__str__` as you had before:

```
class MyCustomUserInline(admin.StackedInline):
    model = Profile
    can_delete = True
    verbose_name = "profile"

    def __str__(self):
        return 'API KEY: ' + str(self.api_key)
```

This way, the result should be:

```
Profile: API KEY: 10c64d48-416f-4fd7-b01d-4328d2536ea2
```

### Why your key is being randomly duplicated?

With `verbose_name = Profile`, Django is using the class `Profile` as name of the line. The fields with the attribute `default` are pre-populated. In this case `api_key` with: `default=uuid.uuid4`.

Answer (score 1):

Change the **`verbose_name`** to a **`STRING`** rather than the **`Model Class`**

```
class MyCustomUserInline(admin.StackedInline):
    model = Profile
    can_delete = True
    verbose_name = "PROFILE" # Change is here <<<<<
```

### Why a **`random`** API KEY showed??

If you are using `verbose_name = Profile`, it uses **`__str__`** method of the model. Unfortunately, there is no such **instance**, hence it uses the **`default`**, and hence returned a ***random UUID***.

### Proof

**Case-1**

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(MyUser, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    api_key = models.UUIDField(default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False, unique=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return 'API KEY: ' + str(self.api_key)
```

```
In [10]: from sample.models import Profile

In [11]: Profile()
Out[11]: <Profile: API KEY: 43065d5f-c7f5-42ea-bf7b-8d82cdb11541>

In [12]: Profile()
Out[12]: <Profile: API KEY: b86abd24-62d0-4d0e-b125-d37a7f14d182>

In [13]: Profile.objects.get(id=1)
Out[13]: <Profile: API KEY: 39aa9839-2ea5-43ca-9bbb-dfb08e48d775>

In [14]: Profile.objects.get(id=1)
Out[14]: <Profile: API KEY: 39aa9839-2ea5-43ca-9bbb-dfb08e48d775>
```

Comment: According to Django documentation, is recommended to use lowercase in name and verbose attributes to facilitate their usage inside phrases.